# Improve efficiency of making a simple array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner so this is definitely common knowledge, so I came here to ask.

If I want to make a very large array that just contains different words, such as this

```
adjectives[0] = "one";
adjectives[1] = "two";
adjectives[2] = "three";
adjectives[3] = "four";
adjectives[4] = "five";
```

This is just a small example, the array I'm actually making is very large. Surely I don't have to hardcode this and do each line one by one. How can I do this more efficiently?

EDIT:

Question has slightly shifted while still on the topic.

I want to turn a txt file like this

A
B
C
D
E

into an array list, which is spit out by the program into the console, for use in another program.

Basically textfile.txt -> program -> arraylist.txt

Comment: Just use a `for` loop.

Comment: For a dynamic size you better use a ArrayList.

Comment: If you're creating an array that contains more than just simple numbers you can calculate in a loop, you'd use an external datasource such as a file or a database. It's unlikely that you'd be using an array as the data structure at that point either, since there are plenty of better ones at your disposal depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Don't use `js` snippets for java code, please. Please have a look at [mcve]

Comment: The answer is still the same after your shift - you are supposed to loop. And if you need an array list, you use an `ArrayList` and its API instead of an array. So read the [Oracle tutorial about lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html), learn about loops, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **for loop** and parse the index of the lop to string:

```
    final String[] foo = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        foo[i] = Integer.toString(i);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for()` loop:

```
String[] adjectives = new String[6]; //first letter of a non-final variable should be lowercase in java
for(int i = 0; i < adjectives.length; i++) { //loop index from 0 to the arrays length
    adjectives[i] = Integer.toString(i) //you could also use an int[]
}
```

Done.

Also take a look at this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to simply assign ascending numbers, then use a `for` loop:

```
int[] adjectives = int[5];
//replace 5 with whatever you want

for(int x = 0; x < adjectives.length; x++){
    adjectives[x] = x
}
```

If you want to place strings/objects in there that don't have some incremental order, then you can condense the assignment statement to a single line:

```
String[] adjectives = {"hey", "there", "world", "hello"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the words are comming from a text variable, you could just split it :

```
String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
String[] words = text.split("[ \n]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Answer (score 0):

read a text file line by line and store each read line into an ArrayList with a BufferedReader 
`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class TxtFileToArrayList 
{

 public static void main(String args[])
  {
    ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();

    try{
    // Open the file     
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("text.txt"/*file path*/);

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String readLine;
    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
          lines.add(readLine);// put the line in the arrayList
    }
    //Close the input stream
    in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any

    }
  }
}
```

`
or use  [readAllLines()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Answer (score -1):

You can use arraylist and then if you really want arrays only then convert arraylist to array datatype--

```
List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<=Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;i++)
            ls.add(Integer.toString(i));

String array[]=ls.toArray(new String[ls.size()]);
```

Comment: This is an unnecessarily inefficient way to create an array. Use a list, or use an array; don't use both.